# Switchery as radio button, cannot toggle back

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle, switchery

Now making playlist using switchery checkbox,
and already make it like a radio button,

but it cant toggle back.

How can i make Switchery back to idle state / unchecked state ??

**[>>> my Fiddle Demo <<<](https://jsfiddle.net/kinggeneral/g94gkaL7/)**

Here is my js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       //switchery
       var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

       elems.forEach(function(html) {
          var switchery = new Switchery(html,{size: 'small',});
       });

       //detect change 
       $('input.pinmusic').on('change', function() { //detect change 
          // auto uncheck when selecting other checkbox
          // but this is not working with switchery
          $('.pinmusic').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
       });
});
```

PS : its already checked, but only switchery get stuck.
already browse some topic of switchery here but still error.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: thx for your suggestion, already edit with more detailed problem in code @BSMP

Answer (score 1):

I'm late but, here's my solution:

```
 var $switches = [];
 var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call();

 $.each(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'),function(i,html) {
     $switches[html.name] = new Switchery(html,{size: 'small',});
 });
 $('input.js-switch').on('change', function () { 
     if (this.checked) {
       $.each(document.querySelectorAll('input.js-switch:not([name="' + this.name + '"])'), 
       function (i, e) {
          switcherySetChecked($switchers[e.name], false)
       });
     }
 });
 function switcherySetChecked(switcher, check) {
     var curr = $(switcher.element).prop('checked');
     var disabled = $(switcher.element).prop('disabled');
     if (disabled) {
           switcher.enable();
     }
     if (check) {
            if (curr) {
                $(switcher.element).prop('checked',false);
            }
            $(switcher.element).trigger('click');
     } else {
            if (!curr) {
                $(switcher.element).prop('checked', true);
            }
            $(switcher.element).trigger('click');
     }
     if (disabled) {
            switcher.disable();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to be sure of your problem, but if I understand well, you want to uncheck a radio button.

Well, you can't. A radio button is not made to be unchecked. The meaning of a pool of radio buttons is "choose exactly one of the following options". Unchecking a radio button would mean that the user chooses zero option, which is not allowed.

From Wikipedia's [Radio button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button):

> A radio button or option button is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options.
>
> It is possible that initially none of the radio buttons in a group are selected. This unselected state cannot be restored by interacting with the radio button widget, though it may be possible through other user interface elements.

What you need to use if you want to be able to choose zero option, is a [Checkbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox).

Comment: i already uncheck it via javascript, only the switchery isnt working

here is [my fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kinggeneral/g94gkaL7/) @Right-leg